# Haircut, buy or pay

Tags: word-choice

In English,a friend and I were arguing whatever we should use "bought a haircut" or "paid for a haircut". Which is more commonly used?

Comment: I would normally say "I *had* a haircut."  If the discussion were about where I spent my money yesterday, then "I *paid for* a haircut."  "Bought" is a hair  *odd* in this context.

Comment: I would normally say "I *got* a haircut" or "I *had* my hair cut."

Answer (score 2):

Most people say "I got a haircut.", but between the two "I paid for a haircut" makes most sense.

I think "bought" is more for tangible objects. Like "bought a computer" or "bought a car", where as "paid for" makes most sense with services like a haircut or paid for housecleaning.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use this phrase: "Paid for a haircut."

"Bought a haircut" doesn't make sense as *a haircut* isn't a good, but rather a service.